# Adding a text field to a UITableview Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

Am new to Ios programming with swift 2.2

What am trying to achieve is inserting two text fields in a uitableviewcell or uitableviewcells

for example the text in the cell will be of  this format

"A vs B"

i want to insert text fields on both sides of the VS 
 so i want it to look like this    "A[Textfield] vs [Textfield]B"

any sort of help will be appreciated

Comment: What's your requirement? can you please elaborate or upload some kinda image which help us to understand your requirement.

Comment: Do you have anything yet? There are mainly 2 ways to solve this: 1) use interface builder to build your cells or 2) create your textfields in the `tableview(_: cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` method.

Comment: @ Arun Kumar   http://topbestfreeapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Live-Soccer-Scores-app.jpg         if you look at that image want i want to add a text field on both sides of the vs so that i can manually enter the scores does that help?

Comment: @Diego  Yes i have already got the table to show "A vs B"  . if i was to use your second method to add the text field how will i go about that i have tried to use the interface builder but the fields never showed up thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a subclass of UITableViewCell with two text field outlets:

   ```
   class TextFieldsCell: UITableViewCell {
       @IBOutlet var textfield1: UITextField!
       @IBOutlet var textfield2: UITextField!
   }
   ```
2. In IB, select your table view and add a prototype cell to your table view by setting "Prototype Cells" to "1", in attributes inspector:

[image]

3. In IB, layout the text fields inside your cell using autolayout. (skipping details of autolayout implementation)

[image]

4. In IB, select your table view cell, and change it's "Identifier" to "TextFieldsCell", in attributes inspector:

[image]

5. In IB, select your table view cell, and change it's "Class" to "TextFieldsCell", in identity inspector:

[image]

6. In IB, connect `TextFieldsCell`'s IBOutlets with the corresponding text fields:

[image]

7. In your view controller which contains the table view, implement the following:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 2;
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell: TextFieldsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextFieldsCell") as! TextFieldsCell
       return cell
   }
   ```
8. If you set everything up properly, you should see this on the next run:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Create a new class and make it a subclass of UITableViewCell and call it something like MyTableViewCell.
- In your Storyboard file click your tableView, then in the right panel click the attributes inspector, choose prototype cells: 1.
- Click your newly created cell and in the attributes inspector choose an identifier name (for instance, "myCellID"). Then in the identity inspector set the class attribute MyTableViewCell.
- Drag and drop the textFields to your cell, then with the assistant editor, ctrl + click and drag from your textFields to your UITableViewCell subclass. It should create outlets for your textFields.
- In your ViewController, make your class implement UITableViewDataSource protocol and override the `tableView(_: numberOfRowsInSection:)` and the `tableview(_: cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`. Then in the latter method write:

  let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCellID") as! MyTableViewCell
  return myCell

Even though we are not using the outlets for the text fields you created, you will need to use them at some point to pre-populate content, set target-action methods, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it entirely from code:

```
import UIKit

struct MatchInfo {
    var teamA: String
    var teamB: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var matches = [MatchInfo]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        // Add some data
        matches.append(MatchInfo(teamA: "Panthers", teamB: "Broncos"))
        matches.append(MatchInfo(teamA: "Bucaneers", teamB: "Falcons"))
        matches.append(MatchInfo(teamA: "Vikings", teamB: "Titans"))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    // MARK: -
    // MARK: Table View Data Source Delegate
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matches.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") ?? makeCell()

        let textFieldA = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextField
        let textFieldB = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UITextField

        let row = indexPath.row
        textFieldA.text = matches[row].teamA
        textFieldB.text = matches[row].teamB

        return cell
    }

    func makeCell() -> UITableViewCell {
        let textFieldA = UITextField(frame: CGRectZero)
        let textfieldB = UITextField(frame: CGRectZero)

        textFieldA.tag = 1
        textfieldB.tag = 2
        [textFieldA, textfieldB].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
        }

        let vsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
        vsLabel.text = "vs."
        vsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        [textFieldA, textfieldB, vsLabel].forEach { cell.contentView.addSubview($0) }

        // Layout the elements
        let views = ["A": textFieldA, "B": textfieldB, "vs": vsLabel]
        let c1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[A]-8-[vs]-8-[B]", options: .AlignAllBaseline, metrics: nil, views: views)
        let c2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldA, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.layoutMarginsGuide, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let c3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textfieldB, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let c4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldA, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let c5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textFieldA, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textfieldB, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(c1 + [c2, c3, c4, c5])

        return cell
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]