# How can I retrieve the data from a text field that is embedded in a UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I've been trying to create a submission form of sorts in a UITableView (i.e. a table view which has a text field in each row), but haven't been able to retrieve the user input from the programatically generated text fields in the table view.

This is the code so far:

```
class VC12: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var VC12TableView: UITableView!

var VC12Inputs = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.VC12TableView.dataSource = self

    VC12Inputs.append("Input 1")
    VC12Inputs.append("Input 2")
    VC12Inputs.append("Input 3")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return VC12Inputs.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = VC12TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") ?? makeCell()
    let textField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextField
    let row = indexPath.row

    textField.placeholder = VC12Inputs[row]

    return cell
}

func makeCell() -> UITableViewCell {
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect.zero)

    textField.tag = 1
    [textField].forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        $0.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    }

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    [textField].forEach { cell.contentView.addSubview($0) }

    let views = ["textField": textField]
    let c1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[textField]", options: .alignAllLastBaseline, metrics: nil, views: views)
    let c2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.layoutMarginsGuide, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let c3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let c4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.9, constant: 0)
    let c5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.09, constant: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(c1 + [c2, c3, c4, c5])

    return cell
}

@IBAction func VC9Done(_ sender: Any)
{

}
```

And this generates a standard table view with 3 text fields; one in each row, i.e. like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOwO0.png

However, I am not sure how to retrieve the text the user inputs into the text fields, when they tap "Done". Any thoughts on the best way to go about this?

The code shown here is based on the Stack Overflow answer by Code Different (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different?tab=profile) from the question ([Adding a text field to a UITableview Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293284/adding-a-text-field-to-a-uitableview-cell)) by B B (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6155520/b-b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this one**

```
class VC12: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var VC12TableView: UITableView!

var VC12Inputs = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.VC12TableView.dataSource = self

    VC12Inputs.append("Input 1")
    VC12Inputs.append("Input 2")
    VC12Inputs.append("Input 3")
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    VC12Inputs[textField.tag] = textField.text! //to update arr with latest value 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return VC12Inputs.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = VC12TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") ?? makeCell()
    let textField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextField
    let row = indexPath.row
    textField.tag = row      //**set tag value here** 
    textField.delegate = self   //**set delegate**

    textField.placeholder = VC12Inputs[row]

    return cell
}

func makeCell() -> UITableViewCell {
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect.zero)

    textField.tag = 1 //don't set tag value here or set with indexpath.item
    . .....
    .....

}

@IBAction func VC9Done(_ sender: Any)
{
    print(VC12Inputs) //here you'll get all updated value at any time 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom class cell, and have the `UITextField` initialization (assign it a variable name) in that class.

```
class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {
    let textField = // initialize text field

    // don't forget to add its constraints and init functions
}
```

Then in your `VC9done` function, you can call your table view's `cellForRow` function and get the cell that contains your desired TextField. Once you get this cell, you can cast it as your custom class and then access its `.textField` field and whatever text it holds.

Comment: You will also need a delegation pattern to update your data model when the text in a text field changes; If the tableview scrolls and cells are reused you will lose any changes if you don't do this.

Comment: I like laying out the UI in the storyboard so I can visually set up the constraints.  This also lets me control-drag from the text field to my view controller to create an IBOutlet. This all avoids having to type cast and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

With the help `UITextFieldDelegate` methods, we can achieve it.

```
var textFieldTextDict = [Int : String]()

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let cellPosition = textField.superview?.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: yourTableView)
    let indPath = yourTableView.indexPathForRow(at: cellPosition!)

    if textField.text != ""
    {
        textFieldTextDict[(indPath?.row)!] = textField.text
    }      

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

@IBAction func VC9Done(_ sender: Any)
{
    self.view.endEditing(true) // ONE LINE

    print("addedValues   ", textFieldTextDict)
}

@IBAction func formSubmitAcn(_ sender: Any)
{
    // as per three textfields

    if textFieldTextDict.count == 3
    {
        print("success")
    }
    else 
    {
        print("failure")
    }
}
```

**OutPut**

```
addedValues   [0: "name ", 2: "age", 3: "address", 1: "email", 4: "phone"]
```